# Given a Global Screen Position in code, how do I figure on which monitor I am on?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, multiple-monitors, coordinate-systems

I am given a global Screen position (x,y), and I have multiple monitors plugged into my Mac computer, how do I in Xcode (Objective-c) figure out which monitor am on.

Basically I need to know which index in the NSScreen list I am on, or how do I retrieve the global monitor space (coordinate system that includes all monitors)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the array of `NSScreen`s, and iterate through it, testing `NSPointInRect( myPt, [aScreen frame] )`.

You don't say where you're getting your global (x, y).  Some OS APIs assume a global coordinate space whose origin is at the top left of the main screen, while I think Cocoa puts the origin at the bottom left.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  My coordinate it coming from a top left coordinate system, but I figured I can convert it, unless there is another method that handles that kind

Comment: Depending on what you plan to do with the screen information, you might be able to use Quartz functions instead, like `CGGetDisplaysWithPoint`.